# Mocha tests with Yeoman and PhantomJS

Tags: requirejs, phantomjs, mocha.js, yeoman

I'm using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) to scaffold my project. It comes with several handy things, including a [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)-based test runner.

My problem is that while my tests run correctly in the browser, they time out while trying to run them with PhantomJS in the CLI.

Here's how my test `index.html` looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="lib/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <!-- assertion framework -->
  <script src="lib/chai.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>

  <script>
    mocha.setup({ui: 'bdd', ignoreLeaks: true});
    expect = chai.expect;
    should = chai.should();
    require(['../spec/map.spec'], function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        require(['../runner/mocha']);
      }, 100);
    });
  </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Here's `map.spec.js`:

```
require(['map'], function (Map) {
  describe('Choropleth Map Generator', function() {
    describe('Configure the map', function () {
      it("should enforce mandatory parameters in the configuration", function () {
        var config = {title: 'test configuration'};
        var map = new Map(config);
        (function () {
          map.getConfig();
        }).should.throw(Error);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now, when I do `yeoman test`, I get this:

```
Running "server:phantom" (server) task

Starting static web server on port 3501

[...]

Running "mocha:all" (mocha) task
Testing index.html
<WARN> PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue. </WARN>

Aborted due to warnings.
```

As I said, `yeoman server:test` shows my assertions correctly in the browser.

I'm using Yeoman 0.9.6 and PhantomJS 1.7.0. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your mocha config In Gruntfile. Do you have something like:

```
mocha: {
  all: ['http://localhost:3501/index.html']
},
```

Comment: It's the default, generated by `yeoman init`. That is -
    `mocha: {
      all: ['test/**/*.html']
    },`

Comment: This made it work for me, but from the first try. More details here - https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/719

Comment: Here's a working template: https://github.com/roblevintennis/yeoman_requirejs_template

Answer (score 4):

I solved that same warning by double-checking the path to `mocha` in `test/index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="lib/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
```

Comment: I still have `mocha.js` referenced in the html, it didn't change it for me. I don't use backbone for my project.

Comment: In my case, I assumed that yeoman would install Mocha when I ran the original webapp generator.  After checking my index path and where it pointed to, I saw it was missing.  `bower install mocha` fixed me up.